# Change IP address of cloned VM - RedHat

Tags: vmware

I cloned a RedHat OS VM using VMSphere Client and the IP address is now the same on both VMs. How can I set/change the IP address of the cloned VM? I've checked several sources but couldn't see any resolution to this problem eg. http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/237224-changing-ip-address-after-cloning-vm/

Comment: Did you clone a running VM? Is the IP address statically assigned, or assigned via DHCP?

Comment: I switched it off and cloned it; static I believe

Answer (score 3):

This question would be better for ServerFault.

With that said, if the address is static, you will need to update your interface configuration file. Use the `ifconfig` command to determine the interface name, this will be `$interfaceName`. You will now need to update the ip address in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-`$interfaceName`. You want to update the IPADDR field. See the Redhat docs here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html.

VMware does not handle the IP addressing, the VM will handle this itself. The reason you have the same IP address is because the file is exactly the same on both VMs. You will also need to update the MAC address in VMware under the network settings tab.

Edit: 
From the VMware KB, "The /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules may also need to be updated to the new MAC address." -http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2002767

Answer (score 0):

I set BOOTPROTO=dhcp and ONBOOT=yes from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 followed by `service network restart` and that set a new IP address to the VM.